# Prove that the cone $S = \{(x,y,z) \in \Bbb R^3 ~|~x^2+y^2-z^2=0 \}$ is not a smooth surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis, smooth-functions, non-smooth-analysis

Prove that the cone $S = \{(x,y,z) \in \Bbb R^3 ~|~x^2+y^2-z^2=0 \}$ is not a smooth surface. The book I am reading - Vector calculus by Peter Baxandall gives the following **hint :** **(Let $S \subseteq \Bbb R^m$ be a smooth surface. Then there exists an open subset $E \in \Bbb R^m$ such that $f$ is smooth on $E$ and $S$ is a level set of the function $f:E \subseteq \Bbb R^m \rightarrow \Bbb R$)**

**Attempt:** Suppose that $S$ is a smooth surface. Then, there exists a smooth function $f: E \subseteq \Bbb R^3 \rightarrow \Bbb R$ such that $$S=\{(x,y,z) \in E~|~f(x,y,z)=0 \}$$

Clearly $(0,0,0) \in S$ as $f(0,0,0)=0$

Consider the three differentiable paths $\alpha.\beta,\gamma$ in $S$ given by :

$$\alpha(t)=\big(t,0,t\big),~~ \beta(t)=\big(0,t,t\big),~~\gamma(t)=\big(t,t,\sqrt 2 t\big), t\in [-1,1]$$

We  can see that $\forall t \in \Bbb R : \alpha(t),\beta(t),\gamma(t) \subseteq S$ because $ f( \alpha(t))= f(\beta(t))= f(\gamma(t))=0$

Then $\alpha'(t)=\big(1,0,1\big),~~ \beta'(t)=\big(0,1,1\big),~~\gamma'(t)=\big(1,1,\sqrt 2 \big)$. We can see that these vectors are linearly independent.

> **This is the direction specified in the book. How do I use this info to obtain a contradiction ? Intuitively, we should now obtain a contradiction by proving that $f$ is not a smooth function. Any hints on obtaining a contradiction will be deeply appreciated**

EDIT: Problem Statement $Q.11$ in the textbook with the hint : [image]

Comment: For smoothness consider the implicit function theorem. Can any of the variables be solved for in a neighborhood around zero ?

Comment: @NinadMunshi I haven't really been introduced to the implicit function theorem in the text. Could you please take a look at my attempt and give me an hint on how to move forward

Answer (score 4):

Let
$$
g(u) = \begin{cases} 
\exp\left(\frac{-1}{u^2}\right) & x \ge 0 \\
0 & x < 0
\end{cases}
$$
Then (after some work) you can show that $g$ is smooth, and $g^{(n)}(0) = 0$ for $n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$.

Now let
$$
h(x, y, z) = x^2 + y^2 - z^2
$$

and
$$
f(x, y, z) = g(h(x,y,z)^2)
$$
Then it's easy to see that

1. $f(x, y, z) = 0$ implies that $h(x, y, z) = 0$ and
2. $f$ is smooth, by the chain rule.

What this means is that the proposed method of proof **cannot succeed**, because I've exhibited a smooth function on 3-space whose zero-set is exactly the cone that you're supposed to show is not a manifold.

How can this be? It appears to be a contradiction!

But that's because either you (in transcribing) or the author (in writing) forgot a critical component of the theorem: a manifold $M$ is always the zero set of a smooth function $f$ *with the extra property* that the gradient of $f$ is nonzero at every point of $M$.

In my example, the opposite is extremely true: the gradient of $f$ is zero at every point of $M$. I could have been more cautious and constructed something whose gradient was zero only at the origin (which is the only "bad point"), but it would have taken more effort and been less clear, so I didn't.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. I have edited my question and added the original question in the book. could you please take a look and advise. If this method is wrong, how should this proved then. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: By editing, I meant i have added the question and hint in it's original form. Just to make sure that I didn't inscribe it wrongly. thanks

Comment: Problem 10 is incorrect as well unless the book has a rather unusual definition of "smooth function". The right "solution" for your problem might be to use a different book that doesn't contain mistakes like this.